Extrapolating Missing Water Level Gage Data - Best Method
I'm interested in what would be the best method to extrapolate what may have been the peak surge elevation given some amount of data and a missing peak value due to the water level gage having topped off. Is there an equation that I could try to do a best fit for? Or should I use statistical methods like ARIMA? Any thoughts would be appreciated.


Is everything in red the missing data that you want to extrapolate?

The real data (blue) flattens out because the gage was maxed out and couldn't read the true maximum value. Therefore, the portion of the red curve that rises above the blue one is the information that I wish to approximate.

I've used PCHIP Interpolator and Univariate Spline Interpolation. Neither gave reasonable results. I'm unfamiliar with ARIMA, but am tempted to learn to see if more reasonable results could be gotten from it.

Obviously, you can't reproduce data that weren't measured.  However, if you have knowledge of the physics of the process that produced this data, you can estimate the small amount of data that was beyond the range of your instrumentation.  That will be a guess, but listing your assumptions in a report to peers or superiors should suffice if those assumptions are based on valid physics.
